# RxJava - Execute several operations on worker thread and merge result into one

Tags: java, multithreading, reactive-programming, rx-java

What I want to do is to execute several operations(say network request) on worker threads, and then merge results of each request into one `List<>`. 
Simplified version of my code looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable.from(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
                .flatMap(integer -> {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        //Simulate long-running operation
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return Observable.just("number: " + integer);
                })
                .toList()
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<String> result) {
                        System.out.println(result);
                    }
                });
    }
```

Now this runs fine, but apparently it's executed on `main` thread. When I add this line before `.toList()`:

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

then nothing is printed into console. What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that your main thread exits before the io threads, which are daemon threads, have a chance to run. So you either use `.toBlocking().forEach()` to wait for the asynchronous computation or add `Thread.sleep(10000)` after the `subscribe()` call.

**Edit**:
The original example is sequential by nature. You can introduce some parallelism by deferring the calculation in the flatMap:

```
Observable.range(1, 10)
.flatMap(number -> 
    Observable.defer(() -> {
        try {
            // computation
            return Observable.just("result: " + number);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            return Observable.<String>error(e);
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());
)
.toList()
.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: That makes sense, and works. But are operations really executed in parallel in this case?

Comment: Yep, because the subscribeOn occurs inside the flatMap. By the way if the items you are processing in parallel are significantly more numerous than the number of processors then you should buffer the operations into lists then in the flatMap process the lists on Schedulers.computation().